# Presence of a copy constructor causes function to return by reference instead of value

Tags: c++

In the following code, it prints out two different memory locations. This makes sense to me as I am returning by value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
        Foo () {}
//      Foo (const Foo &) { cout << "Copy con" << endl; }
};

Foo test () {
        Foo foo;
        cout << &foo << endl;
        return foo;
}

int main () {
        Foo foo = test();
        cout << &foo << endl;
}
```

However, if I uncomment the copy constructor in the above code and run it again, it outputs the same memory location twice. Why? It doesn't print out "Copy con" at all, so I know the copy constructor isn't being called. It seems that the mere presence of a copy constructor causes some sort of optimisation, even though it isn't called.

I'm compiling with a "g++ -Wall test.cpp -o test" on GCC 4.6.3.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Basically, your compiler omits the costly copy operation resulted from the return statement, even though the copy constructor has side effects.

The reasoning behind this is that returning a complex object is costy. Instead of wasting the time on copying, the compiler secretly creates a hidden object in the *caller's* stack frame, and passes the reference to that hidden object to the called function, and the function's return value is copied directly into that hidden object.

The C++ standart states this explicitly (ISO-IEC 14882:2011 12.8 para. 31):

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects.

Comment: So why does this only happen if I declare my own copy constructor?

Comment: @Mike, simply because the standart allows it: `When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects.` - ISO-IEC 14882 12.8 paragraph 31.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Those criteria would seem to be met also for the implicitly defined copy constructor, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB, this is a tough one. I have to admit I don't _know_ why does it not optimize the code with the implicit constructor, but I have two guesses. The first is that the implicitly-created copy constructor is formed in a way that certainly prevents the compiler from using this optimization. The second is that it is just implementation-defined. The standard says `...an implementation is **allowed** to omit...` so this may be simply implementation-specific.